# How could i clear my input field but push my data to database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to clear my input field's ,but when i clear them php pushes empty string to my database .could someone help me?

this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'phpAdd.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });

      function submitForm(){
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.reset(); 
          $('#firstname').focus();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="phpAdd.php" method="post" id="myForm">
        <h1>Please enter your info.</h1>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="firstname"><br>
        Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="lastname"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="SUBMIT" onclick="submitForm()">
       </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

how could i clear the field's after it pushes the data to php?

Comment: put the form reset in the success block of the ajax call instead, your reset is called before by the looks of it, not after